# crashed while dismissing uitextview in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitextview

I have implemented simply a uitextview, when I dismiss it with done button. It got crashed in `iOS 6 with error -[UITextView setSelectable:]: unrecognized selector sent`

but it is working fine in iOS 7.

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView1 
   {
   [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

I am really unable to find the issue. Please help me out if someone has idea regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your crash log.

Comment: @Manimaran   -[UITextView setSelectable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0e7600
2014-02-06 12:30:40.399 PicEvery[2084:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextView setSelectable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0e7600'

Answer (score 1):

You must have return type like this..

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView1 
   {
      [textView1 resignFirstResponder];
      return YES; // put this line in your code.......
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In UITextView.h:

@property(nonatomic,getter=isSelectable) BOOL selectable NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

this property is only available in iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Please have recheck again with Following code:

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView1 {
  [textView1 resignFirstResponder]; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementText:(NSString *)text {

```
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the statement textView.selectable, it works without it on both versions